# Need for application.xml in JavaEE 6 for ejb

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6, application.xml

I have a question similar to [Application Deployment Descriptor in Java EE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990793/application-deployment-descriptor-in-java-ee-6) where the answerer explains that if you want to use custom (non-default) `context-root`, one must define the `application.xml` which should contain all the information for the project.

If I have an EJB, is there any such specific condition/situation for an EJB, where I must define an `application.xml`?

Comment: Last time I checked, application.xml was meant to be defined for EAR projects. For an EJB module you'd have to define an ejb-jar.xml, but as of EJB 3.0 this file is not even mandatory anymore.

Comment: @Henrique Ordine - Thank you.  I realise application.xml is for EAR.  The question really is, when using JavaEE 5.0 or later, are there any conditions where I MUST define an application.xml for ejb.  The example in link above is - you MUST define the application.xml if your context root is going to be different from your web project name, otherwise it can be omitted

Answer (score 2):

The application.xml is not required, and I cannot think of a situation where you would be forced to do it because of an EJB.

Comment: As mentioned above, I know application.xml is not required as of JavaEE 5.0 or later.  But is there a situation for EJB ( as there is for web ) project, where it MUST be defined for the application to work correctly after deployment.

Comment: @adbdkb I can't think of any situation for an EJB, but it's often a must for war modules, where you want to specify a context path.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, only a few additions:

- In general, the deployment descriptor gives you the possibility to overwrite settings done by component defaults or annotations.
- In Java EE there is for most use cases no need to create an EAR deployment, since EJBs can also resist in the WAR.
- Thus, application.xml is optional, so as per se there is no situation where you must have it, but there are those were you may want to have it. Also checkout Pascal's [cite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990793/application-deployment-descriptor-in-java-ee-6).

Comment: An ear deployment allows you to have multiple web modules that share libs and ejb modules. If you package everything in a war, all war deployments have their own copy of everything, their own persistence (and related caches), etc. A lot of times, I'm using ear deployments rather than war.